# Estimating standard deviation from cumulative frequency table

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, frequency

I've been provided with some data in the form of a cumulative frequency table, where each value is exceeded a qiven percentage of the time, so for 99% of the time the readings exceed 163 and for 1% of the time the readings exceed 5930. I have data for each %ile.

From this, how should I calculate the mean and standard deviation?